# Cannot get App built on OS X 10.9 to run on OS X 10.5

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, osx-leopard, libstdc++

### Problem

I've recently upgraded my build environment to Xcode 6.1.1, running on OS X 10.9, and now I'm having trouble getting my application running again under OS X Leopard, 10.5.

For the target, *Base SDK* is set to **OS X 10.6**, and *OS X Deployment Target* is set to **OS X 10.5**. Inspecting the build logs shows that these settings are making their way through to the compilation and link phases (in the form of `mmacosx-version-min=10.5`, `export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5`, etc.)

However, when I run the application under OS X 10.5, it crashes immediately with the error:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found:    __ZNSt15basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE9showmanycEv
  Referenced from: /[path]/[Application Name].app/Contents/MacOS/[Application Name]
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
```

### What I've Tried So Far

A bit of digging around shows that on OS X 10.9, `/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib` is a link to version 6.0.9, and on OS X 10.5 it's a link to version 6.0.4.

Other questions on SO suggest that the answer is to include a copy of the required version of libstdc++.6.dylib in the app bundle, and to point the dynamic linker to it using `install_name_tool`.

So I run the command:

```
install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib @executable_path/libstdc++.6.dylib [Application Name].app/Contents/MacOS/[Application Name]
```

And `otool -L [Application Name].app/Contents/MacOS/[Application Name]` now reports:

```
@executable_path/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
```

I copy `/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib` to the location `[Application Name].app/Contents/MacOS/libstdc++.6.dylib` and copy the application over onto the deployment machine and get...

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found:    __ZNSt15basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE9showmanycEv
  Referenced from: /[path]/[Application Name].app/Contents/MacOS/[Application Name]
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
```

...exactly the same error message.

Running `otool -L` on the application on the deployment machine confirms that the link to `libstdc++.6.dylib` is still pointing to the path under `@executable_path` that I set up with `install_name_tool`.

So why is the dynamic linker ignoring the path set up by `install_name_tool` and still looking in `/usr/lib`?

Is this the correct solution for the problem?

Comment: Why can't you build using the latest SDK?

Comment: @SevenBits It's a legacy app, with lots of calls to long-deprecated functions that have been removed from later versions of the SDK. Updating the entire app was outside the scope of the minor upgrade that was being prepared.