# In what version of OS X was libstdc++.6.dylib updated to point to libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib

Tags: macos, linker, osx-leopard, libstdc++

One obvious workaround to [my earlier question about getting an application to run on OS X 10.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673333/cannot-get-app-built-on-os-x-10-9-to-run-on-os-x-10-5), is simply to drop support for that version.

But that leaves the question of what version of OS X I'd need to set as my minimum deployment target, in order to solve the link errors pasted below (described in more detail in the earlier question)?

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found:    __ZNSt15basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE9showmanycEv
  Referenced from: /[path]/[Application Name].app/Contents/MacOS/[Application Name]
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
```

In what version of OS X was `libstdc++.6.dylib` updated to point to `libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried upgrading to OS X 10.6.3 and libstdc++.6.dylib definitely points to libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib in that version.

(Presumably the change was made in 10.6.)